# Why is Volley returning null value for response object

Tags: android, android-volley

Here is my `onResponse` method

```
public void onResponse(SongInfo response) {

    Log.v("TAG", "Response value is "+String.valueOf(response.artworkUrl30));
    // Prints "Response value is null"
}
```

`String.valueOf(response.artworkUrl30))` should return a URL

Here I set up my request queue singleton

```
Static `mRequestQueue` variable and method 

public static RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

public static RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.getAppContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}
```

Here I make the request to get the the JSON object

(Actually there are multiple JSON object at the [URL](https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=michael+jackson))

```
getRequestQueue();

String JSONURL = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=michael+jackson";

GsonRequest<SongInfo> myReq = new GsonRequest<SongInfo>(
    Request.Method.GET,
    JSONURL,
    SongInfo.class,
    null,
    createMyReqSuccessListener(),
    createMyReqErrorListener());

mRequestQueue.add(myReq);
```

Here is my success response listener with `onResponse` method

```
private Response.Listener<SongInfo> createMyReqSuccessListener() {
    return new Response.Listener<SongInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(SongInfo response) {
            // Do whatever you want to do with response;
            // Like response.tags.getListing_count(); etc. etc.

            Log.v("TAG", "This is the value of the string"+String.valueOf(response.artworkUrl30));
        }
    };
}
```

Here is my error listener

```
private Response.ErrorListener createMyReqErrorListener() {
    return new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // Do whatever you want to do with error.getMessage();
        }
    };
}
```

Here is my `GsonRequest` class

```
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {

    private final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private final Map<String, String> headers;
    private final Response.Listener<T> listener; // success listener

    /**
     * Make a GET request and return a parsed object from JSON.
     *
     * @param url URL of the request to make
     * @param clazz Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
     * @param headers Map of request headers
     */

    public GsonRequest(int method,
                       String url,
                       Class<T> clazz,
                       Map<String, String> headers,
                       Response.Listener<T> listener, // success listener
                       Response.ErrorListener errorListener) { // error listener

        super(method, url, errorListener); // error listener
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.headers = headers;
        this.listener = listener; // success listener
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String json = new String(
                    response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(
                    gson.fromJson(json, clazz),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is `SongInfo` class

```
public class SongInfo {

    public String wrapperType;
    public String kind;
    public Integer artistId;
    public Integer collectionId;
    public Integer trackId;
    public String artistName;
    public String collectionName;
    public String trackName;
    public String collectionCensoredName;
    public String trackCensoredName;
    public String artistViewUrl;
    public String collectionViewUrl;
    public String trackViewUrl;
    public String previewUrl;
    public String artworkUrl30;
    public String artworkUrl60;
    public String artworkUrl100;
    public Float collectionPrice;
    public Float trackPrice;
    public String releaseDate;
    public String collectionExplicitness;
    public String trackExplicitness;
    public Integer discCount;
    public Integer discNumber;
    public Integer trackCount;
    public Integer trackNumber;
    public Integer trackTimeMillis;
    public String country;
    public String currency;
    public String primaryGenreName;
    public String radioStationUrl;
    public Boolean isStreamable;
}
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with `GSON`, but my guess would be that you're trying to cram your `JSON` response into a model (`SongInfo`), that doesn't account for the fact that `artworkUrl30` is in a `JsonArray` called 'results'. Your model probably needs a `List<Result>` results field, and the `Result` object would contain the `artworkUrl30` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can just map the `Json` response as if it's completely flat, and all fields are located at the root of the `Json` hierarchy.

Your `SongInfo` model should probably look like this:

```
public class SongInfo {

    public int resultCount;
    public List<Results> results;
}
```

And you'll need a Results object, something like:

```
public class Results {
    public String wrapperType;
    public String kind;
    .
    .
    .
    public String artworkUrl30;
}
```

Comment: Well when I type `response` in the `onReponse` method, my IDE will display list of attirbutes e.g. `response.artworkUrl30` etc.... I don't know if that means anything to you.

Comment: That tells me that your object contains those fields.. since those are the fields you gave your object when you created it.. My answer still stands, I strongly recommend you give it a try.

Comment: Getting error `cannot resolve symbol response.artworkUrl30` in onResponse method where I wrote  `Log.v("TAG", "Response value is "+String.valueOf(response.artworkUrl30));`

Comment: That's because your artwork url is now a field within your Results object, which is a List<> inside your SongInfo object. So you would need to call Response.results.get(<index>).artworkUrl30, where index is the position of the result you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting an JsonObject as Response use Volley JsonObjectRequest,else
JsonArray as  response, you have to make Volley  JsonArrayRequest.

After getting the response make the Gson to handle the response data with  SongInfo class.

If you are thinking to use other Library for Network call,  I suggest you this, 
[enter link description here](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

Comment: The response is a JsonObject, the problem is the GSON model isn't structured in a way in which GSON is able to map the array results to a List.

Comment: Yes @TimMalseed,  artWorkUrl30 is inside Results array. SongInfo class have to be changed like you mentioned.