# volley returns null in onresponse

Tags: android, json, asp.net-web-api

i created this api using asp .net, but when i call it to get the value of firstname and lastname it returns null

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "Male",
        "lastName": "Hastings",
        "gender": "Male",
        "salary": 60000
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "Male",
        "lastName": "Hastings",
        "gender": "Male",
        "salary": 60000
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "firstName": "Ben",
        "lastName": "Hoskins",
        "gender": "Male",
        "salary": 70000
    }
]
```

and this is my android code where i call the api, i just need to get the value of firstname and lastname without the ID and Gender, it looks like it reads the api but it fails to parse the data

```
 if (isConnectingToInternet(getApplicationContext())) {
                JsonArrayRequest itemrequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSON

Array response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    //SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("mypref",0);
                    // SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Items items = new Items();
                            items.setName(obj.optString("FirstName"));
                            items.setDescription(obj.optString("LastName"));
                            itemsList.add(items);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    String credentials = "" + ":" + "";
                    String encodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_WRAP);
                    headerMap.put("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);
                    try {
                        headerMap.putAll(super.getHeaders());
                    } catch (AuthFailureError authFailureError) {
                        authFailureError.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return headerMap;
                }
            };
             //requestQueue.add(itemrequest);
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(itemrequest);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Volley returning null value for response object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991640/why-is-volley-returning-null-value-for-response-object)

Comment: show your work please

Comment: by the way, my api has no authentication, i tried to remove the header and see what happens but still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the parser is case sensitive, it works with key value pair, where key is case sensitive

change below lines from

```
items.setName(obj.optString("FirstName"));
items.setDescription(obj.optString("LastName"));
```

to

```
items.setName(obj.optString("firstName"));
items.setDescription(obj.optString("lastName"));
```

Comment: loool, i cant believe it. how did i miss this. thank you

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that your request data is correct and in JSONObject form?

if you are sure, check these with breakpoint:
1- your request data
2- you header
i think your request in not in correct format.